# Painting multiple faces issue

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

uhh, I'm new to Texture Paint and while experimenting paint brush, I've come across this problem...

[image]
and this is its UV Image
[image]

Please help me on how do I remove these edges on the paint's outlines and make it accurate to its UV lines.

Comment: check if you have the option for painting only selected faces, it's in the bottom panel

Comment: @PaulGonet, yeah, found out it was the "bleeding" before I found that page lol, my bad.